# Get "AudienceName" using "AudienceID" in sharepoint 2013 (c# code)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development, audience-targeting

I have a GUID for audiences. but I need the "AudienceName" to perform the another operation. how to I get the audienceName using AudienceID in c# code.

Please suggest any idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
AudienceManager AudMgr = new AudienceManager();
Audience AudObj = AudMgr.GetAudience(new Guid(AudienceID));

if (AudObj != null)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Audience Name {0}", AudObj.AudienceName);
}
```

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms498416.aspx

Comment: I am having an "Access Denied" error in "Audience AudObj = AudMgr.GetAudience(new Guid(AudienceID));" code. i used the 'run with elevated permission' also it says "Access Denied". please provide any idea.

Comment: please refer this link that i have come across. This may help you out.  --> https://mariuszgorzoch.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/audiencemanager-in-context-of-w3wp/